# Swift PKPayment Request error

Tags: ios, swift, ios10.3

I'm currently working with a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController and presenting it to validate a payment within my application. I am able to present the controller but receive an error stating "Invalid in-app payment request. PKPaymentRequest must contain a property 'countryCode' of type 'NSString'". I have set the country code for the payment request and still receive this error. Attached below if the code I'm using to create the payment request and present the controller. I have X'd out my merchant ID for the purpose of posting. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController()
                applePayController.delegate = self

                let request = PKPaymentRequest()

                let supportedPaymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.visa, PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, PKPaymentNetwork.amex, PKPaymentNetwork.discover]
                let applePayMerchantID = "merchant.com.xxxxxxxxxx.XXXXXXXXXXX"

                request.countryCode = "US"
                request.currencyCode = "USD"
                request.merchantIdentifier = applePayMerchantID
                request.supportedNetworks = supportedPaymentNetworks
                request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS


                let price = Decimal(self.creditsPrice[index])
                let priceDecimal = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: price)

                request.paymentSummaryItems.append(PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "for \(self.credits[index]) Credits", amount: priceDecimal))

                applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)

                self.paymentName = self.credits[index]
                self.paymentValue = self.creditsPrice[index]

                if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: supportedPaymentNetworks) {

                    self.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {

                    self.displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please setup Apple Pay before trying to purchase credits")
                }
```